# HTML Multiple Drop Down Box Not Linking Properly

Tags: javascript, html

I added two drop down boxes to my website containing URL to different pages, however the problem I'm experiencing is, if I go to a URL from the first drop down box, come back to the page and then select a link from the second drop down box, it automatically goes to anything selected on the first drop down box. I think I can write two seraprate scripts, but I'm trying to do it in a single script as it is. Any input? I'm new to Java and HTML

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
 function go()
 {
 window.location=document.getElementById("link").value
}
</script>



<form>
<select id="link" onchange="go()">

    <option value="url1">link1</option>

</select>
</form>
<form>
<select id="link" onchange="go()">
  <option value="url2">link2</option>


</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML attribute id's are meant to be unique to each element. If you have more than one element with `id=link` and you call `getElementById('link')`, it will return **only the first** of them because it is only ever expecting to find one.

To do what you are trying to do in pure JavaScript (someone better at JavaScript correct me if I'm wrong), change `id=link` to `class=link` and try something like:

```
dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
for (var i=0; i<dropdowns.length; i++)
    dropdowns.onchange = function(){ window.location.assign(this.value); }
```

Note that this will probably not always work because some browsers, for security, will resist assignments to `window.location`. Also, if you are having trouble, consider perhaps using the jQuery framework as it makes such things considerably easier:

```
$('.link').change(function(){
     // do something
});
```

Comment: But my script only contains "Link" wouldn't that automatically point to "Link". I just tried and it didn't work, the script looks for "Link"

Comment: Sorry I got called away. Expanded my answer to hopefully provide a better explanation

Comment: Yup it does. Thank you. For now I've just consolidated the drop down to a single box.